# Discord PY API endpoint change

Tags: python, api, url, discord, bots

I want to change the the API endpoint of the bot so It can wokr for a alternative instance of discord api.
For now I'll keep the url hidden for some reaosns I won't explain at the moment. I have only have little docs on this and barley can get it to work.

This is my code:

```py
#token is in enovirment
import os
#import discord/disocrdpy
import discord

#change the api url
discord.http.Route.BASE = "Discord Alterative URL"

#setup intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True


#setup bot token
token = os.environ['token']
#make the client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

#tell when the bot has logged in
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user} (ID: {client.user.id})")

#run the bot with minimal erors
try:
    client.run(token)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

I've gotten these errors

```
2023-05-03 11:26:46 INFO discord.client logging in using static token
Error: string indices must be integers
```